# Android fragment onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, onactivityresult

## Edit

It seems that i need to call `startActivityForResult(intent, requestcode);`

Would i do something like this on my main parent activity:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
getActivity();
if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
   //some code
}
```

and then start my intent like this? Still not sure...

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DietActivity.class);

    Bundle bundle = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.left_slide_in, R.anim.left_slide_out).toBundle();
    intent.putExtra("id", dietid);
    intent.putExtra("duration", diet_duration);
    intent.putExtra("weightlost", total_weight_loss);
    intent.putExtra("followers", followers);
    intent.putExtra("rating", rating);
    intent.putExtra("dietname", dietname);
    intent.putExtra("dietdescription", dietdescription);
    intent.putExtra("dietcategory", dietcategory);

    startActivityForResult(intent, bundle, 1);
```

## Old

I have main activity which launches a fragment, this fragment then starts another temporary activity which shows some information using the code below:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DietActivity.class);

    Bundle bundle = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.left_slide_in, R.anim.left_slide_out).toBundle();
    intent.putExtra("id", dietid);
    intent.putExtra("duration", diet_duration);
    intent.putExtra("weightlost", total_weight_loss);
    intent.putExtra("followers", followers);
    intent.putExtra("rating", rating);
    intent.putExtra("dietname", dietname);
    intent.putExtra("dietdescription", dietdescription);
    intent.putExtra("dietcategory", dietcategory);

    getActivity().startActivity(intent, bundle);
```

When i  call `finish()` on this new activity the same fragment which was previously visible is shown, i want to change this fragment to another when the launched activity is finished but i would like to put some extra information as shown on the new fragment, Do i use `onActivityResutls` here? not sure any help would be great

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to get data in DietActivity?

Comment: Hi, I already get the Data in DietActivity class, this class only shows information, now on diet activity after the use has viewed the information and Finish() is called on the activity I would like to replace the fragment which calls this intent, this is actually part of another main class

Answer (score 0):

Yes using `OnActivityResult` is a way to go.
You can override it in the caller activity or caller fragment. If you only want to do a fragment transaction or any other work that is related to activity, override onActivityResult in you activity. Also note that you should use `startActivityForResult` to specify a request code so that you can handle the result for that request code.

You can also override it in your fragment, if you want to just update the data in the fragment or simply handling it there.

EDIT:
To send data to your new fragment, you can use a static factory in your fragment to receive a new instance like this:

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(Bundle args){
    MyFragment f = new MyFragment();
    f.setArguments(args);
    return f;
}
```

Instantiate your fragment using `MyFragment.newInstance();`
Then to use these arguments, in your for example `onCreate` method of fragment you can access the bundle you supplied using `getArguments()` method.

Comment: Hi, i think you are right here, I have edited my question, so i start this new activity using startActivityForResults, then when the result is send back as that activity finished i would like to replace the fragment but still pass some information to that new fragment is that posible?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.
Use static builder for your fragment, and pass data to it in a bundle, or using parameters.